# Conditions on a and b in Master theorem

Tags: asymptotics

Should the $a$ and $b$ in Master theorem be integers or they can be rational numbers? I think $a$ must be an integer but $b$ can be rational.

Comment: I don't see a problem in them being rational (or even irrational) numbers. That being said, you will probably never really need to use this case (since in realistic algorithms $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers). Still, I'm not 100% sure that you can use this theorem when they are rational or irrational numbers, so please don't take that as granted.

Comment: They don't have to be integers. The proofs go through for any constant $a>0$ and $b>1$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks.